# Как сделать, чтобы поля не падали друг на друга?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть поле ввода текста. Есть label, который находится в этом поле. Когда нажимаю на поле для ввода текста - label поднимается вверх и я ввожу свой текст, но после ввода(т.е., когда мышей кликаю где-то на экране) label опускается на своё место и, таким образом, падает на введённый текст. Помогите сделать так, чтобы при заполненном поле label оставался на своём месте.

P.S. JS код отсутствует, но если он необходим, тогда давайте на чистом JS.

```css
input {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 17%;
}
label {
  margin: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}
input:focus ~ label, input.used ~ label {
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <link href="./text.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="text"><span class="highlight"></span><span
    class="bar"></span>
  <label for="text">TEXT</label>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Если только средствами css.**

Задаем `input` атрибут `required` и в css условие `input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label { ... }`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  top: 55px;
  
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label {
  top: 20px;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="text" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label for="text">TEXT</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**2. Вариант с использованием jquery (если кому-нибудь другому понадобится):**

```js
$('input').on('focusin', function() {
  var 
  $this = $(this),
      row = $this.closest('.form-group'),
      label = row.find('label');

  row.addClass('active');
});

$('input').on('focusout', function() {
  var 
  $this = $(this),
      row = $this.closest('.form-group'),
      label = row.find('label'),
      val = this.value;


  if (!val) {
    row.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  top: 55px;
  
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.active label {
  top: 20px;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label for="text">TEXT</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное братан, мне помог этот кусок кода, на который я изменил свой: input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label

Answer (score 3):

```js
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  this.parentNode.dataset.top = this.value ? 1 : 0
})
```

```css
label {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 14px;
}

label[placeholder]::before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5;
}

label[data-top="1"]::before {
  top: -2px;
  left: 2px;
  transform: translateY(-100%)
}

label[placeholder] input {
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<label placeholder="Write me...">
  <input type="text" id="input">
</label>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное братан.